# List last_name, firstly show on top letter with start 'C' then list all

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my code it is not true.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPJWW.png)

[image]

Comment: Hi. Could you please reword your question to make it a bit more clear? Are you asking for a query that selects the column first name, starting with the letter C? What is your table name? What database are you using?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select last_name 
from employees 
order by case substr(last_name,1,1) 
              when 'C' 
              then 1 
              else 2 end
```

Comment: This solution is not totally correct, as it correctly puts first words starting with 'C', but checks only that, ''global' order isn't kept

Comment: Add a `, last_name` to the "order by" to sort on names after putting the "C"s first

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

It adds an underscore before the words starting with 'C', so it keeps the order of words but, as underscore comes before 'A', will list those word first

```
select last_name
from employee
group by last_name
order by case 
           when upper(substr(last_name,1,1))='C' 
                 then concat('_',last_name) 
                 else last_name end
```

Answer (score 0):

A rough and dirty solution might be:

```
SELECT
    last_name
FROM
    employees
WHERE
    (last_name LIKE [C-Z]%)
ORDER BY
    last_name DESC
```

That way, we are saying to give us the columns where the last name starts with any letter C-Z (so, the alphabet with A and B excluded), and then ordering it by starting with C

Comment: But now you are ignoring those names starting with A or B

Comment: Isn;t that what OP wanted?

Comment: I *assume* that "then list all" means that A and B should be included

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ascii` function with `abs` in the order by clause :

```
select last_name
  from employees 
 order by abs(ascii(substr(last_name,1,1))-67);
```

`67` is the ascii code of `C`, and for the other values you always get an integer value which are more than `zero` from `abs(olute)` value function.

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/AXBDO29136)

Comment: This does mean that the resulting order is something like C,B,D,A,E,F,.. (A and B mixed with D and E), instead of C,A,B,D,E,F,... But the OP didn't specify in what order the rest should be, so this may still be correct

Comment: @HansKeﬆing yeah, exactly as you summarized.